# Código javascript para obtener cuanto falta para dos fechas no funciona en Safari

Tags: javascript, safari

Hola tengo el siguiente código que es un contador que dice cuanto falta de una fecha a otra, si me corre bien en Chrome, Windows, Android, etc. pero en Safari no funciona, lo probé en un Iphone y no funciona

```js
var date = '2021-03-21 12:20:30';
var second_date = '2021-04-21 13:00:00';
function renderCountdown(dateStart, dateEnd){
    //console.log(dateStart, dateEnd);
    var currentDate = dateStart.getTime();
    var targetDate = dateEnd.getTime(); // set the countdown date
    var days, hours, minutes, seconds; // variables for time units
    var count = 0;
    var getCountdown = function (c){
          var secondsLeft = ((targetDate - currentDate) / 1000) - c;
          days = pad( Math.floor( secondsLeft / 86400 ) );
          secondsLeft %= 86400;
          hours = pad( Math.floor( secondsLeft / 3600 ) );
          secondsLeft %= 3600;
          minutes = pad( Math.floor( secondsLeft / 60 ) );
          seconds = pad( Math.floor( secondsLeft % 60 ) );
          if(days != 'NaN'){
            console.log(days + " days " + hours + " hours " + minutes + " minutes " + seconds + " seconds");
          }
      };
    getCountdown();
    setInterval(function () { getCountdown(count++ ); }, 1000);
}
function pad(n) {
    return (n < 10 ? '0' : '') + n;
}
renderCountdown(new Date(date),new Date(second_date) );
```

No estoy seguro a que se debe este detalle en Safari

Comment: Viendo las tablas de compatibilidad de acorde con MDN, todas las funciones y la sintaxis que usas son válidas para Safari. Trata de ver la consola para ver qué error arroja el código, o en su defecto usar [`try/catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) e imprimir el error en pantalla.

Comment: Gracias Rodrigo lo intentaré, es que no tengo un iPhone entonces tengo que andar pidiéndole a un amigo que me diga si le sale en su iPhone, agregaré el try catch, y te aviso en cuanto mi amigo lo cheque

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo logré el problema era con la fecha, tuve que cambiar la fecha de esta forma `new Date(Date.parse(date.replace(/[-]/g,'/')))` cambiando - por /

```js
var date = '2021-03-21 12:20:30';
    var second_date = '2021-04-21 13:00:00';
    function renderCountdown(dateStart, dateEnd){
        //console.log(dateStart, dateEnd);
        var currentDate = new Date(Date.parse(date.replace(/[-]/g,'/')));
        var targetDate = new Date(Date.parse(second_date.replace(/[-]/g,'/')));
        var days, hours, minutes, seconds; // variables for time units
        var count = 0;
        var getCountdown = function (c){
              var secondsLeft = ((targetDate - currentDate) / 1000) - c;
              days = pad( Math.floor( secondsLeft / 86400 ) );
              secondsLeft %= 86400;
              hours = pad( Math.floor( secondsLeft / 3600 ) );
              secondsLeft %= 3600;
              minutes = pad( Math.floor( secondsLeft / 60 ) );
              seconds = pad( Math.floor( secondsLeft % 60 ) );
              if(days != 'NaN'){
                console.log(days + " days " + hours + " hours " + minutes + " minutes " + seconds + " seconds");
              }
          };
        getCountdown();
        setInterval(function () { getCountdown(count++ ); }.bind(this), 1000);
    }
    function pad(n) {
        return (n < 10 ? '0' : '') + n;
    }
    renderCountdown(new Date(date),new Date(second_date) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Recuerdo que hace tiempo saffari tenía problemas con las funciones setInterval y setTimeout, se corregía agregándole `bind(this)`:

```js
var date = '2021-03-21 12:20:30';
var second_date = '2021-04-21 13:00:00';
function renderCountdown(dateStart, dateEnd){
    //console.log(dateStart, dateEnd);
    var currentDate = dateStart.getTime();
    var targetDate = dateEnd.getTime(); // set the countdown date
    var days, hours, minutes, seconds; // variables for time units
    var count = 0;
    var getCountdown = function (c){
          var secondsLeft = ((targetDate - currentDate) / 1000) - c;
          days = pad( Math.floor( secondsLeft / 86400 ) );
          secondsLeft %= 86400;
          hours = pad( Math.floor( secondsLeft / 3600 ) );
          secondsLeft %= 3600;
          minutes = pad( Math.floor( secondsLeft / 60 ) );
          seconds = pad( Math.floor( secondsLeft % 60 ) );
          if(days != 'NaN'){
            console.log(days + " days " + hours + " hours " + minutes + " minutes " + seconds + " seconds");
          }
      };
    getCountdown();
    setInterval(function () { getCountdown(count++ ); }.bind(this), 1000);
}
function pad(n) {
    return (n < 10 ? '0' : '') + n;
}
renderCountdown(new Date(date),new Date(second_date) );
```

Comment: Gracias el problema era en el formato de la fecha